# How to run the Calculate Field using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I have an issue in executing the Calculate field command in Python (ArcPy). I couldn't find any related resources or helpful descriptions regarding this. I hope somebody could help me with this.

```
inFeatures = r"H:\Python Projects\PycharmProjects\ArcPy\Test_Output\Trial_out.gdb\Trail_Data_A.shp"


arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, 'ObjArt_Ken', '!AttArt_Ken!'.split('_')[0])
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, 'Wert', '!AttArt_Ken!'.split('_')[-1])
```

The error i am getting when I run the command is

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Error during execution. Parameters are invalid.
ERROR 000989: The CalculateField tool cannot use VB expressions for services.
Error while executing (CalculateField).
```

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these two expressions:
`'!AttArt_Ken!'.split('_')[0]` and `'!AttArt_Ken!'.split('_')[-1]`.

When you write an expression in Calculate Field tool, you must enter a single string that contains a
code sample. You want to split the text that the field contains, therefore, you write the name of the
field (enclosed in exclamation points), and on that you do the split method.

The proper way is this:

```
inFeatures = r"...\Trail_Data_A.shp"

arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, 'ObjArt_Ken', "!AttArt_Ken!.split('_')[0]")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, 'Wert', "!AttArt_Ken!.split('_')[1]")
```

**Note:** It is worth checking that the path is a valid path for a shapefile. What you posted shows a shapefile that is inside File Geodatabase (`r"...\Trial_out.gdb\Trail_Data_A.shp"`), which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1):

I found a working output for the above mentioned question

```
inTable = r'H:\Python Projects\PycharmProjects\ArcPy\Test_Output\Trial_out.gdb\Trail_Data_A.shp'

func_1 = "'!AttArt_Ken!'.split('_')[0]"
field_1 = "ObjArt_Ken"

func_2 = "'!AttArt_Ken!'.split('_')[1]"
field_2 = "Wert"

arcpy.AddField_management(inTable, field_1, "TEXT".encode('utf-8'))
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, field_1, func_1, "PYTHON_9.3")

arcpy.AddField_management(inTable, field_2, "TEXT".encode('utf-8'))
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, field_2, func_2, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

But a problem still exists such that the output (After split function) is like
|ObjArt_Ken|Wert|
|:---|:---|
|u"31001|1001"|

I still couldn't figure out a way to remove the unicode or the '"' symbol from the desired output

Answer (score -1):

*Since I can't comment yet, I will have to use an Answer to make several comments*

You need to clarify, "I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8 and Python 2.7."  ArcGIS Pro has always come bundled with Python 3.x, and ArcGIS Desktop/ArcMap has always been bundled with Python 2.x.  It is not possible to use ArcGIS Pro and Python 2.7.  Given the error message, it appears you are running some version of ArcMap and Python 2.7.

The original error message, as you seemed to have figured out, was telling you exactly what wasn't working originally.  Since you didn't pass `expression_type` to Calculate Field and you are using some version of ArcMap that defaults to `VB`, the function was interpreting your expression as VB code and erring because "CalculateField tool cannot use VB expressions for services."

Looking at the newer code, I am not sure why you are encoding `field_type`.  Although I tested it and it works, it is unnecessary and confusing to someone looking at the code.

Unless you provide some samples of what the AttArt_Ken field contains, people can't really comment on the output you are seeing.